# heats (context: sport)-- what are those?

Tags: meaning

Source: [Slow English Podcasts about Australia for intermediate learners of English](http://slowenglish.info/?p=2118)

Example:

> I and my family were lucky enough to attend the 2000 Olympics when they were held in Sydney.  We drove up from Melbourne in our car. To get tickets to the events, you had to enter a ballot which was held many months before the games.  We didn’t get our first choice of sports, but we were fortunate to get tickets to the field hockey, the Taekwondo and finally a day at the track and field athletics in the main stadium, when **heats were being run**.

I can't figure out what they mean by *heats*. Any idea?

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/heat see meaning 3, A preliminary round in a race or contest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[Heat](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/heat)*** is used to refer to  one of a series of efforts or attempts to do something, specifically in Sports:

> - (Sports & Games)  One round of several in a competition, such as a race.

(AHD)

[Heat](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/heat):

> - a) a single course in or division of a race or other contest.
> - b) a race or other contest in which competitors attempt to qualify for entry in the final race or contest.